# Resize jpeg images only where the quality >80 using either mozjpeg/jpegtran/jpegoptim

Tags: jpeg, libjpeg-turbo

Hi I want to resize jpeg image that were uploaded as optimized, but because of a software error all recoded to 100% jpeg quality. (so we upload say 80% quality image and after upload it is 100% quality and the filesize is enormous!)

So how can I
- 1st find *only* jpeg images file that have a `quality setting > 80` or better `quality setting == 100`
- and optimize these images *only* to a `quality setting = 80`

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [jpegoptim](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/jpegoptim.1.html) for compress images using command "jpegoptim --all-progressive --strip-com --strip-exif --strip-iptc --strip-xmp -T1 -m80"